# AppleScript for Outlook 2011 for Mac to save all attachments to external drive and then remove them from emails

Tags: macos, applescript, email-attachments, outlook-2011

I have an Outlook 2011 (Mac) version of this question: [save all email attachments in outlook folder to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952909/save-all-email-attachments-in-outlook-folder-to-folder?rq=1)

And, I've seen AppleScripts at places like this: https://www.27partners.com/2012/03/strip-attachments-from-outlook-2011-using-applescript/

BUT, I need to make sure the attachments are saved (not just deleted) to an external drive (the point of all of this is to free hard drive space).

Does anyone have a simple AppleScript that saves (to a file folder) & deletes attachments (again, not just deleting or just saving)...for all emails in Outlook 2011? Even if it's only possible for all emails in a folder (rather than all folders at once), that would be a close silver medal.